# How to change MySQL Workbench editor highlighted text background color?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to change background color of highlighted text in query editor of MySQL Workbench? It seems it's somehow set to very unreadable default, as shown in the picture:

[image]

In comparison, this is the same snippet when it's not highlighted:

[image]

My environment: Windows 10, MySQL Workbench 8.0.17 Community Edition.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited post... Win 10, MySQL Workbench 8.0.17

Comment: It seems this is fixed in 8.0.18